# How to fix " java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.setValue"

Tags: android, dictionary, firebase-realtime-database, geofire, currentlocation

I'm setting up a current location in my application.Where do i need to set the encoding?

```
    @Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    mLastLocation = location;
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(11));

    //Geo Fire for current location
    String userId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
    DatabaseReference refAvailable = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("driversAvailable");
    DatabaseReference refWorking = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("driversWorking");

    GeoFire geoFireAvailable = new GeoFire(refAvailable);
    GeoFire geoFireWorking = new GeoFire(refWorking);

    switch (customerId){
        case "":

            geoFireWorking.removeLocation(userId);
            geoFireAvailable.setLocation(userId, new GeoLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()), new GeoFire.CompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(String key, DatabaseError error) {

                }
            });

            break;
            default:
                geoFireAvailable.removeLocation(userId);
                geoFireWorking.setLocation(userId, new GeoLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()), new GeoFire.CompletionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(String key, DatabaseError error) {

                    }
                });

                break;
    }


}
```

Following is error which I'm getting:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.setValue
>   at com.firebase.geofire.GeoFire.removeLocation(GeoFire.java:215)
>   at com.firebase.geofire.GeoFire.removeLocation(GeoFire.java:192)
>   at com.example.webforest.quickaidlikeuber2nd.DriverMapActivity.onLocationChanged(DriverMapActivity.java:184)

Comment: Can you try using `geoFire.setLocation(userId, new GeoLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()), new GeoFire.CompletionListener(){
});` instead

Comment: It's worked!!!!! Thank you very much

Comment: Glad I could help... I'll post this as an answer so it can be removed from unanswered questions list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bug appears to manifest automatically when you are using `setLocation()` method without the use of `GeoFire.CompletionListener()`. If you implement the `CompletionListener`, this should resolve the issue.
Therefore, replace

```
geoFire.setLocation(userId, new GeoLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));
```

with

```
geoFire.setLocation(userId, new GeoLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()), new GeoFire.CompletionListener(){ });
```

Edit 2: 
**You may need to adapt to a different approach if you are still encountering difficulties.**

Replace the following code:

```
geoFireAvailable.setLocation(userId, new GeoLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()), new GeoFire.CompletionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(String key, DatabaseError error) {

    }
});
```

With the following code:

```
GeoHash geoHash = new GeoHash(new GeoLocation(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude()));
Map<String, Object> updates = new HashMap<>();
updates.put("g", geoHash.getGeoHashString());
updates.put("l", Arrays.asList(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude()));
geoFireAvailable.setValue(updates,geoHash.getGeoHashString());
```

Comment: i face again same problem while i use switch case in  \n switch (customerId){
            case "":
                geoFireWorking.removeLocation(userId);
                geoFireAvailable.setLocation(userId, new GeoLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()), new GeoFire.CompletionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(String key, DatabaseError error) {

                    }
                });

Comment: @Raifur-rahim edit the question with the new code, problem and what you are trying to do. I'll review it

Comment: @Raifur-rahim check the answer again

Comment: Sir I'm new comer if u kindly describe specifically then it will be helpful

Comment: @Raifur-rahim lol, don't refer to me as 'Sir'... I know it's respectful but I am not at that level yet. I've edited the answer, have another look

Comment: u r a respectable person for me .That's why i'm happy to mention u as a sir

Comment: I check the answer again but now it says 'error: cannot find symbol method setValue(Map<String,Object>,String)' @Nero

Answer (score 1):

Geofire has changed a bit, now to make a removeLocation  work you have to add a listener like this:

```
 //after updating 
                    geoFireWorking.removeLocation("id of the node you want to remove", new GeoFire.CompletionListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(String key, DatabaseError error) {

                        }
                    });
```